# Trying to simulate a shelf of books in HTML CSS: How to resize books, keep aligned to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to simulate a shelf of books so that they look like this:
[photoshop_mock_up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcTzd.png)

I can get the books to align just fine, but can't figure out how to make them retain their odd heights/widths, and not all just resize to the container:

HTML:

```html
<div class="images-outer">
    <div class="image-inner">
        <img src="img/_0002_aristotle__poetics_and_rhetoric.png">
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <img src="img/_0005_david_mamet__make_believe_town.png">
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <img src="img/_0003_david_mamet__bambi_vs_godzilla.png">
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <img src="img/_0006_annie_dillard__pilgrim_at_tinker_creek.png  ">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.images-outer {
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.image-inner img {
    max-height: 100%;
} 

img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

This makes them look like this: [web_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GfXj.png)

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In `display: flex`, you should use `align-items` to set vertical align and `justify-content` for horizontal align.

```css
.images-outer {
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:flex-end;
    justify-content:center;
    background: black
}

.image-inner {
    max-width:30px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

.image-inner {
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: bottom;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-outer">
        <div class="image-inner">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/200" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-inner">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/240" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-inner">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/180" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-inner">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/200" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful. That said, it didn't work when I added the actual images. I'm trying to scale the images to viewport size while not flattening them. So - the height won't be set to actual pixels... I tried a variety of methods, but couldn't figure out how to scale the images *and* not go to height:100%.

Comment: How about putting the images into `div.image-inner`, and give the images `width:100%; object-fit: contain; object-position:bottom`? This way, `div.image-inner` will set the width of each book, and the images will be put into the bottom of the div while keeping aspect ratio. `div.image-inner`'s height should be set larger than the tallest book, mimicking the shelf height.

Comment: @elwinjransom Now I updated the snippet to include some example image. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: looks great! Let me try it out!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either, as there's no way to scale the items. Once I applied transform: scale(.5) everything went crazy.

Comment: I just manually resized everything manually and it works great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
.image-inner img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;}
```

This should help in sizing the images properly

Else, you could dive each image an individual class and give each it's individual height.